# ValueChanged Event on a DateTime Picker in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm using a DateTimePicker in C# and I'm having a little problem with the ValueChanged event. I have the CheckBox visibility set to true on the DateTimePicker.

When I use the mouse the set the CheckBox the ValueChanged event fires. Great.

However when I set the CheckBox in code (see below) the ValueChanged event doesn't fire!?

```
dateTimePicker1.Checked = true;
```

Any ideas?

I'm using C# 4.0

Comment: how do you know the `ValueChanged` event fires when you set the CheckBox ?

Comment: I have a break point in the code

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an omission from the MS Developer to lay a general event `ValueChanged` but looks like you are looking for `CheckValueChanged` event.

There are similar post discussion before and one possible *solution* is to create inherits control to handle CheckValueChanged event , you can refer to [DateTimePicker check box event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/27dd3141-5dfb-439e-8e30-e051a019303a/)

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueChanged` event will only fired if you have set the `Value` property. You set with the mouse the `Value` property, so the `ValueChanged` Event will fired. If you set the `Checked` property, the `ValueChanged` event won't fired, because the `Value` property wasn't set.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make sense. I use the mouse the set the CheckedState via checking the check box and the ValueChanged event fires. Surely setting the Checked value in code is the same as using the mouse!? I'm not changing any date value here.